# folding hash function in clojure

Tags: clojure, hash-function

A folding hash function breaks its input (int, in this case) to segments of p length and adds those parts. If `(not (= (mod input p) 0 ))`, that is, the input's length is not a multiple of p, the last segment may be of an arbitrary length less than p.

Here's my code so far:

```
(def firstX
  (fn [x item]
    (take x (str item))))

(def remX
  (fn [x item]
    (drop x (str item))))

(def divItemEq
  (fn [a digits]
      (cond (> digits (count (str a))) (a)
            true (cons (list (firstX digits a)) (divItemEq (remX digits a) digits)))))

(def sumDigits
  (fn [x]
    (reduce + x)))

(def exItem1 76123451001214)
(print (sumDigits (divItemEq exItem1 3)))
```

At the moment, infinite recursion (stack overflow) occurs because the recursive condition in divItemEq is never met. My attempts to fix this have resulted in various type/casting errors.

**Any suggestions to how improve `divItemEq`?**

Comment: You've explained the actual behavior (`StackOverflowError`); could you give the expected/desired behavior?

Comment: Desired behavior: (divItemEq exItem1 3) evaluates to ((761) (234) (510) (012) (14)), which is passed to sumDigits. That application yields 1531. Sidenote: I corrected the recursive case upon second examination. I anticipate that my troubles stem from my elementary understanding of Clojure's type system.

Comment: Use [`partition`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition) instead.

Comment: I was looking to avoid built in functions, but thanks for the suggestion of `partition` @jmargolisvt

Comment: I suppose my trouble is converting the int input to something like a lat (list of atoms)

Comment: @DavidShaked If you're looking to avoid built-in functions, why are you using `take`, `str`, `drop`, `>`, `count`, `cons`, `list`, `reduce`, `+`, and `print`?

Comment: @Elogent looking to avoid built-in function *to an arbitrary extent*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite some things to be improved here, the first would be to use the more idiomatic `defn` instead of `(def name (fn` scheme. The next would be your names which I find to be not very clear. Others have pointed you in the direction to use `partition`, which I would agree to, but in the solution below I tried to keep to the spirit of your approach.

As you've discovered yourself, it makes a lot of sense to turn the number into a sequence of digits, because we're gonna need sequence operations anyway. So let's start with that:

```
(defn decimal-digits [number]
  (letfn [(ddigits-helper [number result]
              (if (number > 0)
                  (recur (int (/ number 10)) (conj result (mod number 10)))
                  result))]
     (ddigits-helper number '())))
```

This approach uses simple math to collect the numbers. It also shows the use of `recur` for recursion and uses an accumulator (the `result` argument) to collect intermediate results.

Here are your two initial functions which we assume to operate on a list of digits now:

```
(defn new-part [number size]
  (take size number))

(defn rest-part [number size]
  (drop size number))
```

As discussed, you could also use `partition` or `split-at`.

Now, your main function could look like this:

```
(defn partition-number
        [number size]
        (let [digits (decimal-digits number)]
          (cond (> size (count digits)) digits
                true (cons (new-part digits size)
                           (partition-number 
                              (digits-to-decimal (rest-part digits size)) 
                              size)))))
```

This is very close in style to your approach but shows that we need to turn the digits back to a number because that's what `partition-number` expects.

```
(defn digits-to-decimal [digits]
  (let [powers-of-ten (iterate (partial * 10) 1)
        digits (reverse digits)]
    (reduce +
        (map-indexed (fn [position digit]
                         (* digit (nth powers-of-ten position)))
                     digits))))
```

However, if we restructure `partition-number` to also use a helper function with an accumulator, we can also use `recur` which is how one can avoid blowing the stack on recursive calls in clojure:

```
(defn partition-number
  [number size]
  (letfn [(partnumb-helper [digits size result]
               (cond (> size (count digits)) (conj result digits)
                     true (recur (rest-part digits size) 
                                 size
                                 (conj result (new-part digits size)))))]
     (partnumb-helper (decimal-digits number) size '[])))
```

Note that this way we also spare to convert between numbers and digits all the time.

Comment: Beautifully answered

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what other core functions you don't want to use but I came up with the following solution:

```
(defn chars->int [chars]
  (Integer/parseInt (apply str chars)))

(defn int-partition [n count]
  (loop [acc [] xs (str n)]
    (if (seq xs)
      (recur (conj acc (chars->int (take count xs))) (drop count xs))
      acc)))

(int-partition 76123451001214 3)
;; yields
[761 234 510 12 14]

(reduce + (int-partition 76123451001214 3))
;; yields
1531
```

Note that this version is not lazy and may be inappropriate for large inputs. You might want to modify it using [`lazy-seq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-seq).